# How to share our post in linkedin from our site using shareArticle

Tags: html, linkedin-api

I have to share the profile to linked in from my website.I tried shareArticle in linkedin url.It is not working for localhost.What i have to do?. Here  sharelink is the link that will hold the candidate profile
 it is not working for localhost . how to configure for localhost.I alse tried with Ip

It should go to the linked in page and post but it showing oops not found

Answer (score 0):

Since `localhost` is not available on the Internet, it isn't possible to LinkedIn to access it (which it needs to in order to fetch the preview data).

So you can't.

Publish your site on the Internet instead.

Comment: I want to test my link is working correctly . Is there any way to check easily without deployment

Comment: Give your development environment a public-facing URL on the Internet.

Comment: I have installed SSL on my local environment. but still i am  not able to share image on linkedin.

Comment: @Shivrudra — That has nothing to do with anything I suggested in this answer.